# The inference of Nothing type in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was going through kotlin documentation and I saw this snippet:

```
fun fail(message: String): Nothing {
    throw IllegalArgumentException(message)
}
```

in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type) they states that `throw` is an expression and it's type is `Nothing`, so I omitted the return type of the above function.

but here is the issue intellij reported that the return type to be `Unit`, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

When you omit the return type, `Unit` is inferred. In reality, that function actually "returns" `Nothing`, but `Nothing` is a subtype of every type, so that works.

"Returns" in quotes because the function doesn't return at all, and that's the purpose of `Nothing`.